# Apexchart annotations label style

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

I use Apexcharts annotations and I suddenly needed to change the label style.

[image: demo]

I need to add something like a pseudo-element to get about that:

[image: demo]

```
annotations: {
    points: [{
        x: new Date("18 Nov 2019").getTime(),
        y: 100,
        marker: {
            size: 8,
            fillColor: '#ffffff',
            strokeColor: '#ffffff',
            radius: 2,
            cssClass: 'apexcharts-custom-class'
        },
        label: {
          borderColor: "#FF4560",
          offsetY: 0,
          style: {
            color: "#fff",
            background: "#FF4560"
          },

          text: "Point Annotation (XY)"
        }
    }]
},
```

Is there a possibility for the script?